# Is it possible to generate code using Roslyn on build?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Right now I am trying to write custom code generator for mapper using Roslyn. I've tried to use CodeFixProvider, but it only suggests codefix, and you should refactor every part by your hands. And I want to just press F5 to generate all needed files. Is it possible in Roslyn?

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Arnott's [CodeGeneration.Roslyn](https://github.com/AArnott/CodeGeneration.Roslyn) library is the most complete implementation of a code generator that runs on build. You should be able to just use this library wholesale or look into how it works and write a fork that does what you want.